# SAS: convert date to Year Month Code

Tags: sas, format

How do I convert `06JAN2005`(as date format) to `200501` (as a number)

Comment: 06JAN2005 or 06JUN2005? 200601 or 200605 in your post?

Comment: You need to be more clear in what `200605` means, as there's no direct link between those two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are only two different variable types in SAS - character and numeric.  Dates are stored in numeric variables and are generally formatted to appear as user-readable dates.  Specifically, dates are stored as the number of days since 01JAN1960.

So if you have a number already formatted as a date, and would like it to appear formatted differently (but still be a number) you simply need to change the format.

As Joe's comment says - I can't see the relationship between the date you provided and the number you desire (maybe you have a typo?).  But the below piece of code will demonstrate how you can simply change the format to change the appearance of the number:

```
data _null_;
  format date1 best.
         date2 yymmddn6.
         date3 date9.   
         ;
  date1 = '06JAN2005'd;
  date2 = '06JAN2005'd;
  date3 = '06JAN2005'd;
  put date1= date2= date3=;
run;
```

Gives:

```
date1=16442 date2=050106 date3=06JAN2005
```

Comment: Can I have just YYYYMM? For example, 200506?

Comment: @user1481397 Yes -  the format for that is `yymmn6.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want an explicit numeric value, you can use the date functions on your date variable which, as pointed out, is a numeric date value SAS understands.

newdatevar=100*year(olddatevar)+month(olddatevar)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
data a;
  attrib 
    v_input format=date.
    v_output_n format=8.;
  v_input = '06JAN2005'd;
  v_output_n = put(v_input,yymmn6.);
run;
```

Comment: This doesn't do what it needs to.  You are `input`ing an already numeric value incorrectly.

Comment: I find this answer very confusing.  Why are you using formats combined with input/put statements, combined with attrib format statements.  I think this is more likely to confuse anyone asking this type of question than to help them.

Comment: I am confused and the code run through, but it generate a new data set with two columns and 1 obs.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you mean you need year||month then something like this should work:

```
data two;
set one;  
    order_month = month(date);
    order_year = year(date);
    order = put(compress(order_month||order_year),6.)-0;
run;
```

Disclaimer being I'd reccomend just formatting whatever else you have properly, so you don't need to represent the date as a number. If you're looking to add or substract increments of dates, you might want to look at the intx function too

Comment: Your general idea is right, but I have to -1 because of the unnecessary character-numeric conversion warning.  Use `input` instead of `-0`.

Comment: Or a better option is simply `order = cats(order_month, order_year);`.  That will concatenate,  trim, and do the conversion for you.  Pipe symbols for concatenation should rarely be used these days.

Comment: I need 201005 instead of 20105. I tried three methods, all give me 20105.